# How to pack files into a ZIP file which have same name but different suffixes?

Tags: batch-file

Here is an example for one file:

- C:\folder\video\my-holiday-video.mp4
- C:\folder\image\my-holiday-screen.png
- C:\folder\mix\my-holiday-HDphoto.jpg
- C:\folder\cover\my-holiday-art.jpg

What I try to do is to make a ZIP archive of files which are in different folders, but have the same name, i.e. `my-holiday` for the example above, but a different suffix as `-video` or `-screen` or `-HDphoto` or `-art` and keep the same folder tree in each ZIP file.

The result should be `my-holiday.zip` which contains all the files in their folders.

I have success with this code on all the files have the same name:

```
@for %%I in ("%~dp0wheel\*") do @"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -bd -bso0 -mx0 -r -x!*.zip -y "%~dp0%%~nI.zip" "%~dp0%%~nI.*"
```

But it zips only when files have all the strict same file name.

Is there a way to make my batch ignore the suffixes `-video`, `-screen`, `-HDphoto` and `-art` in the name of each file in order to make them zip together?

Here are the requirements:

1. The suffixes `-video`, `-screen`, `-HDphoto` and `-art` are always the same for all my files. So these are fixed in the file names.
2. There should be in the file `my-holiday.zip`:

   - video\my-holiday-video.mp4
   - image\my-holiday-screen.png
   - mix\my-holiday-HDphoto.jpg
   - cover\my-holiday-art.jpg

   Each file is with its relative path in the ZIP archive. So when I decompress them, they'll be extracted in their directories, for example `my-holiday-video.mp4` will decompress into folder `video`, `my-holiday-HDphoto.jpg` into folder `mix`, etc. like my actual code do it.
3. The rule for common part of a files collection is that everything left to `-video` before file extension `.mp4` should be used as common part of the file names to pack into the ZIP file.
4. The folder `video` is the source for packing the files with common name into a ZIP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task could be done with following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "C:\folder" || exit /B
for %%I in ("video\*-video.*") do (
    set "VideoFileName=%%~nxI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "CommonName=!VideoFileName:-video%%~xI=!"
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -bd -bso0 -mx0 -y -- "!CommonName!.zip" "cover\!CommonName!-art.*" "image\!CommonName!-screen.*" "mix\!CommonName!-HDphoto.*" "video\!VideoFileName!"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The batch file defines with the first two command lines the required execution environment which is:

- command echo mode turned off
- command extensions enabled
- delayed expansion disabled

The next command changes the current directory to `C:\folder`. If that command fails because of the directory does not exist or a UNC path is used instead of a path starting with a drive letter and a colon, the batch file processing is exited without any further message than the error message output by command **CD**.

The **FOR** loop searches in subdirectory `video` for non-hidden files matching the wildcard pattern `*-video.*`. The file name with file extension of a found video file matching this wildcard pattern is assigned to the environment variable `VideoFileName`.

Next [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled as required to make use of the file name assigned to the environment variable `VideoFileName`. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details on what happens in background  on execution of `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and later on execution of corresponding `endlocal`.

A case-insensitive string substitution using delayed expansion is used to remove from video file name `-video` left to the file extension and the file extension itself which can be `.mp4`, `.mpg`, `.mpeg`, etc. `VideoFileName` was defined with file extension in case of the file name itself contains anywhere the string `-video` which should not be removed by the string substitution. For example `My Home-Video-video.mp4` assigned to `VideoFileName` results in `My Home-Video` getting assigned to the environment variable `CommonName` because of taking also the file extension into account on string substitution.

Next *7-Zip* is executed with the command `a` and the switches as posted in question to create or add to a ZIP file in current directory with common name part of the files in the four directories and file extension `.zip` the video file name and the other image files from the other three directories with whatever file extension the images have in the other three directories.

Then `endlocal` is executed to restore the previous environment with delayed expansion disabled again.

The commands `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `endlocal` are used inside the **FOR** loop to be able to process correct also a files collection with a common name like `Superman & Batman (+ Robin!)` containing an exclamation mark.

The video files in subdirectory `video` define which files to pack into a ZIP file. So all image files in the three image directories are ignored for which no video file exists in directory `video`.

**Note:** The batch file is not capable processing correct video file names which contain an exclamation mark in the file extension. I doubt that this limitation is ever a problem as I have never seen a video file extension with an exclamation mark.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of conditional operator `||`.

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thanks for your detailled and clear answer which help me to understand. WD