# Filename in the output of FOR /f looping through command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here is a bit from one file named "filename1.aof" :

```
SSLTE_RRCMSG|2022-01-31 18:48:30.026083|LTE
rrcConnectionReconfiguration|1510558947||DL DCCH
SSLTE_RRCMSG|2022-01-31 18:48:30.028253|LTE rrcConnectionReconfigurationComplete|1510558991||UL DCCH|10 00
SSLTE_NASEMMTIMER|2022-01-31 18:48:30.028307|0|0|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Event|2022-01-31 18:48:30.123049|0|Voice|"SIP Rx"|152/3/1/0|invite sip:]:6200 sip/2.0||
Event|2022-01-31 18:48:30.123049|0|Voice|"Call Start MtoM Ter"|1/5/0/0|282||
Event|2022-01-31 18:48:30.123049|0|Voice|"SIP Connecting"|20/0/0/0|2A01:CD01:0009:271F:0000:000A:D30C:3701||
Event|2022-01-31 18:48:30.123628|0|Voice|"SIP Tx"|152/2/1/0|sip/2.0 183 session progress||
SSLTE_RRCMSG|2022-01-31 18:48:30.122785|LTE ueCapabilityEnquiry|1510559636||DL DCCH|38 00 40
```

I'm running a FOR /F that is going through **several** of those files, named *.aof :

```
FOR /F "tokens=2,5,7 delims=|" %G in ('findstr /I /C:"Sip Rx" /C:"Sip Tx" *.aof') DO @echo %G;%H;%I
```

The current output is :

```
2022-01-31 15:02:57.531681;"SIP Rx";sip/2.0 200 ok (Invite)
2022-01-31 15:02:57.532269;"SIP Tx";ack 
2022-01-31 15:03:29.037216;"SIP Tx";bye 
2022-01-31 15:03:29.337172;"SIP Rx";sip/2.0 200 ok
```

I need to get the current filename repeated at the beginning of each line of the output, like this :

```
filename1;2022-01-31 15:02:57.531681;"SIP Rx";sip/2.0 200 ok (Invite)
filename1;2022-01-31 15:02:57.532269;"SIP Tx";ack 
filename1;2022-01-31 15:03:29.037216;"SIP Tx";bye 
filename1;2022-01-31 15:03:29.337172;"SIP Rx";sip/2.0 200 ok
```

Because I need to identify the file from which each line is coming from.

Thanks everyone !

Edit : using this command for now, but it only states the filename *before* listing the extracted lines ... I then need to post-process it in excel.

```
FORFILES /M *.aof /C "cmd /c echo @file & findstr /I /C:\"Sip Tx\" /C:\"Sip Rx\" @file"
```

Comment: Using `FORFILES` is probably the worst solution.  Especially if you are processing many files.  It is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Batch file for the data collection task

The batch file for searching in all *.aof files for the strings `SIP Rx` and `SIP Tx` and write the data of interest into a CSV file with name `SIP Rx_Tx.csv` in wanted format is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "eol=? tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:"SIP Rx" /C:"SIP Tx" *.aof 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=: tokens=2,5,7 delims=|" %%I in ("%%H") do echo %%G;%%I;%%J;%%K)>"SIP Rx_Tx.csv"
if exist "SIP Rx_Tx.csv" for %%I in ("SIP Rx_Tx.csv") do if %%~zI == 0 del "SIP Rx_Tx.csv"
endlocal
```

### Short description of the batch file

The command **FINDSTR** searches in all *.aof files in current directory for lines containing either `SIP Rx` or `SIP Tx` and outputs each line with file name at beginning separated by a colon from the line with found string.

The outer **FOR** splits up each line into two substrings (tokens) using `:` as string delimiter. The first substring is the file name without path assigned to the specified loop variable `G`. The second substring is the line in the file assigned to next loop variable `H`.

The line in the file assigned to loop variable `H` is processed further with a second **FOR** to split it up into several substrings using `|` as string delimiter.  The second vertical bar delimited substring is assigned to the specified loop variable `I`, the fifth substring to next loop variable `J` and the seventh substring to next but one loop variable `K`.

The file name assigned to `I` and the three data of interest in found line are output with command **ECHO**. This output is written into the file with name `SIP Rx_Tx.csv` in current directory.

The created CSV file is deleted in case of being an empty file because of no *.aof file is found in current directory or no *.aof file contains one of the two searched strings.

### Full description of the batch file

Here is also a description of the few command lines explaining in full details why the command lines are used as it can be seen above and how they work.

#### Definition of the execution environment

The first two command lines define completely the required execution environment for the batch file which is:

1. Command echo mode turned off to prevent the display of the executed commands during execution or writing them into the CSV file.
2. Command extensions enabled as required for `for /F`.
3. Delayed expansion disabled to process correct also file names and data containing one or more exclamation marks.

An exclamation mark `!` in a string assigned to one of the loop variables would be interpreted as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference if delayed expansion would be enabled on processing the two **FOR** commands. That would result in replacing `!string!` by the value of the referenced variable with name `string` respectively removal of `!string!` if there is no such variable. A single `!` would be just removed with enabled delayed expansion. That is not wanted here and for that reason it is good practice to explicitly disable delayed expansion instead of depending on status for delayed expansion defined outside of the batch file.

#### Correct specification of redirection operator >

The Windows command processor instance processing the batch file parses next the third command line containing twice the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) `>`. But only the second `>` is for `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. The first `>` in that command line is for another `cmd.exe` instance and must be therefore escaped with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

#### Creation of output file

The Windows command processor creates now first the file `SIP Rx_Tx.csv` in current directory with overwriting an existing file with that name. That could fail if the current directory is write-protected or there is already a file with name `SIP Rx_Tx.csv` which is write-protected by file system permissions or read-only file attribute. However, it is expected by this batch file that the creation of the output file is successful as the batch file cannot really do the task if the creation of the output file fails for whatever reason.

The output CSV file remains open until the processing of all *.aof files is finished completely preventing other processes running in background to open the CSV file.

It would be also possible to use as third line in the batch file:

```
for /F "eol=? tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:"SIP Rx" /C:"SIP Tx" *.aof 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=: tokens=2,5,7 delims=|" %%I in ("%%H") do echo %%G;%%I;%%J;%%K>>"SIP Rx_Tx.csv"
```

That is not so good. It would be necessary to first make sure that the file `SIP Rx_Tx.csv` does not exist already in current directory, for example from a previous execution, by using the command **DEL**. But even more problematic is that with this command line the CSV file is handled as follows for each write operation:

1. The CSV file is opened by `cmd.exe`.
2. The file position is set to the end of the file.
3. The output line is appended to the file.
4. The file is flushed and closed by `cmd.exe`.

So on writing hundreds of lines to the CSV file, the CSV file is opened, extended and closed hundreds of times which is not very efficient. It makes it also possible that another process like an anti-virus application running in background opens the CSV file between two write operations for scanning the data in the file preventing `cmd.exe` to append the next data to the file resulting in some data not written to the CSV file.

So the usage of `(` and `)` around the entire command line with the two **FOR** commands and **ECHO** improves the efficiency on writing the data to the output file and prevents an unwanted loss of data by other processes running in the background and accessing the CSV file too.

#### Searching with FINDSTR in background for the data of interest

The outer **FOR** loop should run the command **FINDSTR** and process the lines output by this command. For that reason the `cmd.exe` process which is processing the batch file starts now in background without a visible console window one more `cmd.exe` with option `/c` and the command line specified within `'` appended as additional arguments. The executed command is as follows on Windows being installed in `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:"SIP Rx" /C:"SIP Tx" *.aof 2>nul
```

**FINDSTR** executed by `cmd.exe` started in background searches now first in current directory for files with file extension `.aof` in long or short file name. If there is no file matched by this wildcard pattern, then **FINDSTR** would output to standard error stream (**STDERR**) an error message which would be captured by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and would output the error message to its own standard error stream resulting in getting displayed this error message in the console window if there is a console window opened for `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. That error message is not wanted and for that reason `2>nul` is used to redirect the error message to device **NUL** to suppress it.

**FINDSTR** searches in each found file with file extension `.aof` in current directory

- case-insensitive because of option `/I` and
- literally because of option `/L` (and also because of using `/C:` on omitting `/L`)
- for lines containing either the string `SIP Rx` or the string `SIP Tx`.

The usage of `/C:` is necessary to get interpreted the space character as literal character to search for and not as OR expression. The usage of `"SIP Rx"` as search string would result in searching for the string `SIP` OR the string `Rx` which is not wanted here. For that reason the two search strings are specified with using twice the option `/C:`.

It would be also possible to use **FINDSTR** with the arguments `/I /R /C:"SIP [RT]x" *.aof` to search with a regular expression for one of the two strings in the lines of each *.aof file with space being interpreted as literal space character.

**FINDSTR** outputs to standard output stream (**STDOUT**) of background `cmd.exe` the lines containing one of the two searched strings with file name without path at beginning separated with a colon from the line in the file.

So there is output for `filename1.aof`:

```
filename1.aof:Event|2022-01-31 18:48:30.123049|0|Voice|"SIP Rx"|152/3/1/0|invite sip:]:6200 sip/2.0||
filename1.aof:Event|2022-01-31 18:48:30.123628|0|Voice|"SIP Tx"|152/2/1/0|sip/2.0 183 session progress||
```

That is the output to process further with the two **FOR** commands.

There is no error message output by **FINDSTR** if there is at least one *.aof file and no line found containing one of the two searched strings.

#### Processing of the found and output lines by outer FOR

The `cmd.exe` instance processing the batch file captures all lines output to **STDOUT** of background `cmd.exe` by **FINDSTR** and processes them once `findstr.exe` terminated itself resulting in `cmd.exe` started in background closed itself.

Empty lines are always ignored by `for /F` which is no problem here as there are no empty lines output by **FINDSTR** at all.

There would be split up each captured non-empty line by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab character as string delimiters. That line splitting behavior is modified with `delims=:` to split the line up on colons.

The first substring is checked for beginning with the end of line character which is by default the semicolon. It is very unlikely that a file name of a *.aof file begins with `;`, but it is possible. For that reason `eol=?` is used to change the end of line character to a question mark which no file name can ever contain.

The first substring is assigned to specified loop variable and all other substrings would be ignored by default. That behavior is not wanted here. Everything after first (series of) `:` should be kept as is without splitting it up. Therefore `tokens=1*` is used to instruct **FOR** to assign the first substring (the file name) to the specified loop variable `G` and everything after the colon (the line) without splitting it up to next loop variable `H` according to the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

#### Processing of the data by inner FOR

The line from the *.aof file assigned to loop variable `H` of which file name is assigned to loop variable `G` must be processed further to get just the data of interest. A second `for /F` is used for this purpose to process the **string** assigned to loop variable `H`.

This time a vertical bar is used as string delimiter because of the *.aof files contain lines with `|` separated data.

The end of line character is defined with `:` as the string assigned to loop variable `H` definitely does not start with a colon. If a line in a *.aof file starts with one or more colons, they would be removed already by the outer **FOR** command on splitting up the line output by **FINDSTR** into file name and line.

The data of interest from each line containing `SIP Rx` or `SIP Tx` are the date/time in second `|` separated substring, the found string in fifth data column and the string in seventh data column. For that reason `tokens=2,5,7` is used to assign these three substrings to the loop variables `I`, `J` and `K`.

Please note that `||` or even more vertical bars in series is interpreted by `for /F` like a single `|` on using `delims=|`. So `for /F` is not capable processing empty data values correct in a CSV file using vertical bar as separator. That is no problem in this case.

#### Writing the data in wanted format to CSV file

The command **ECHO** is used to output with a semicolon as separator the file name assigned to loop variable `G`, the date/time assigned to loop variable `I`, the found string assigned to loop variable `J` (with the double quotes) and the additional string assigned to loop variable `K` to standard output stream of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file which is redirected to the CSV file being opened all the time during processing the found lines.

The usage of `%%~J` would result in removing the double quotes from the found strings.

#### Deletion of the CSV file on being empty

It is possible that the output CSV file `SIP Rx_Tx.csv` is created in the current directory, but is finally an empty file because of no *.aof file is found in the current working directory or none of the *.aof files contains one of the two searched strings.

The fourth command line checks the existence of the output CSV file in current directory and next its file size and deletes the file on existing, but being empty, i.e. has a file size of 0 bytes.

#### Restore of initial execution environment

Finally the initial execution environment is restored with execution of command **ENDLOCAL** which would be implicitly executed by `cmd.exe` on not being explicitly written into the batch file.

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

### Help on used Windows commands

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `setlocal /?`