# Trying to rename all files ending with "VA.pdf" to "PA.pdf" using batch code

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hello I am trying to  rename all files ending with "VA.pdf" to "PA.pdf" using batch code

I tired this code but it is not working

`REN *VA.pdf *PA.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

There can be used for this file renaming task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist "*!*VA.pdf" goto ExtendedVersion

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *VA.pdf /A-D-L /B 2^>nul') do (
    set "FileNamePDF=%%~nI"
    set "FileNameNew=!FileNamePDF:~0,-2!PA%%~xI"
    if not exist "!FileNameNew!" ren "!FileNamePDF!%%~xI" "!FileNameNew!"
)
endlocal
goto EndBatch

:ExtendedVersion
echo INFO: Extended version required because of a PDF file with exclamation marks.
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *VA.pdf /A-D-L /B 2^>nul') do (
    set "FileNamePDF=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "FileNameNew=!FileNamePDF:~0,-2!PA%%~xI"
    if not exist "!FileNameNew!" ren "!FileNamePDF!%%~xI" "!FileNameNew!"
    endlocal
)

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

There is defined first the required execution environment with the first two command lines.

The **IF** condition in the third command line quickly checks if there is any PDF file with case-insensitive `VA` in the file name before the file extension `.pdf` containing one or more exclamation marks in the file name. The extended version of the processing loop is required if this condition is true.

The standard version enables first required [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Then a **FOR** loop is used which runs in background with Windows installed into `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir *VA.pdf /A-D-L /B 2>nul
```

The internal command **DIR** of `cmd.exe` searches

- in the current directory as defined by the process starting `cmd.exe` for processing the batch file
- for just file names because of option `/A-D-L` (attribute not directory and not link)
- matching case-insensitive the wildcard pattern `*VA.pdf` in long or short 8.3 name
- and outputs in bare format because of option `/B` just the file names with file extension, but without file path.

An error message output to handle **STDERR** (standard error) on **DIR** does not find any file system entry matching the criteria is suppressed by redirecting this error message to the device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file captures all output written to standard output stream of in background started `cmd.exe` and processes it line by line after started `cmd.exe` closed itself after finishing executing the command **DIR**.

**FOR** with option `/F` is used here to get a list of file names of `*VA.pdf` files loaded into memory of `cmd.exe` before really doing the file renames as otherwise it could happen especially on FAT drives (FAT32, exFAT) that some PDF files are skipped or processed more than once (on rename not possible).

**FOR** on using option `/F` ignores always empty lines which is no problem here as **DIR** with the used options does not output empty lines.

**FOR** would next split up the lines into substrings using horizontal tab and normal space as string delimiters, would look next if first tab/space separated string begins with a semicolon in which case it would also ignore the entire line for further processing, and would otherwise assign just the first tab/space separated string to the specified loop variable `I` before running the commands in body of **FOR**.

The default line splitting behavior is not wanted as PDF file names can contain one or more spaces. The usage of the option `delims=` defines an empty list of delimiters which turns off the line splitting behavior.

It is very unusual but nevertheless possible that a PDF file name begins with `;` (semicolon). Such a file name should not be ignored by **FOR**. The option `eol=|` defines a vertical bar as end of line character which no file name can contain ever. Microsoft lists the characters not allowed in a file name on Windows file systems in the documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

The current file name without file extension `.pdf` is assigned first to the environment variable `FileNamePDF`.

Next a string substitution is used to get from the string value of the environment variable `FileNamePDF` the file name without the last two characters `VA` concatenated with the string `PA` and the file extension `.pdf` assigned to the environment variable `FileNameNew`.

If there is not already a PDF file ending with `PA` in the file name before the file extension, there is next executed the command **REN** to rename the `*VA.pdf` file to `*PA.pdf`.

The command **ENDLOCAL** after the loop restores the previous environment before enabling delayed expansion and the command **GOTO** instructs the Windows Command Processor to continue processing the batch file with the command line below the label `EndBatch` which contains one more **ENDLOCAL** to restore the environment on starting the batch file processing.

The extended version is nearly the same as the standard version. The difference is that delayed variable expansion is not enabled on assigning the file name of the current `VA.pdf` file without the file extension to the environment variable `FileNamePDF`. That avoids interpreting the exclamation mark(s) in the file name as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference resulting in a manipulation of the file name string before assigning it to the environment variable as it would happen with delayed expansion already enabled.

The extended version enables next delayed variable expansion inside the loop, does the same as the standard version and restores finally the previous environment before processing the next `*VA.pdf` file.

The extended version is slower because of the environment variables list copy and the other operations made in background by every execution of **SETLOCAL** as explained in full details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564). The command **ENDLOCAL** in the loop is required to avoid a stack overflow on processing lots of PDF files.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`