# How do you set an environment variable in a subroutine when setlocal is enabled?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use [setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)/[endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) to use some environment variables internally in a script, but then I do want the script to ultimately save some environment variables as output (i.e., that *do* take effect in the calling environment).

I thought I could simply have a `setlocal` at the beginning, and then wrap any `set` commands I want to do outside the script with an `endlocal` before and `setlocal` after. But it seems to have different behavior if done inside a subroutine vs. outside.

This script should have `%var1% == test1` in the calling environment, but *not* have `%var2% == test2`.

```
@echo off

:main
setlocal
call :set_var1
set var2=test2
exit /b

:set_var1
endlocal
set var1=test1
setlocal
exit /b
```

However, when I run this, I see:

```
D:\>set var1=

D:\>echo %var1%
%var1%

D:\>set var2=

D:\>echo %var2%
%var2%

D:\>test.bat

D:\>echo %var1%
%var1%

D:\>echo %var2%
%var2%
```

So the script failed to set `%var1%`.

If I "inline" the code (i.e. cut and paste the code inside the subroutine in the same spot as the subroutine call, and delete the subroutine call), so the script should do the same thing, then it works:

```
@echo off

:main
setlocal
endlocal
set var1=test1
setlocal
set var2=test2
exit /b
```

The output looks like:

```
D:\>set var1=

D:\>echo %var1%
%var1%

D:\>set var2=

D:\>echo %var2%
%var2%

D:\>test.bat

D:\>echo %var1%
test1

D:\>echo %var2%
%var2%
```

So now `%var1%` was correctly set to `test1` by the script.

I'm wondering if the `exit /b` that returns from a subroutine has some effect on setlocal/endlocal. I don't see anything in the /? usage about this.

How do you selectively have a few environment variables created, or modified, in the batch script, take effect in the calling environment, but in general have most of the variables used for intermediate steps, discarded (i.e., treat them as local to the script)?

Comment: The standard trick is: start :set_var with `setlocal` and terminate it with `for %%v in (%var1%) do endlocal & set "var1=%%v"`, that is, in the subroutine _first_ close the environment with `endlocal` and _then_ assign the variable in the _calling_ environment. The value is held in the FOR parameter...  A simpler method is enclose between parentheses these lines: `endlocal` and `set "var1=%var1%"` that have the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest following:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:main
call :set_var1
set "var2=test2"
rem Other commands which define other environment variables like:
set "var3=test3"
endlocal & set "var1=%var1%" & set "var3=%var3%"
exit /B

:set_var1
set "var1=test1"
goto :EOF
```

There is defined once completely the required execution environment at top of the batch file with the first two command lines. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

The command line with `endlocal` is parsed by the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` as described by [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) The environment variable references `%var1%` and `%var3%` are replaced by the current values of these two environment variables in local environment of the batch file.

The finally executed `endlocal` command line does not contain anymore environment variable references. The command line on execution is:

```
endlocal   & set "var1=test1"   & set "var3=test3"
```

The additional spaces are inserted by `cmd.exe` on parsing the command line.

There is first restored the initial environment on starting the processing of this batch file and then is defined the environment variable `var1` with the string `test1` and next `var3` with the string `test3` in that environment.

See also:

- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

There is used `goto :EOF` to exit the subroutine `set_var1` and `exit /B` to exit the processing of the batch file. The reasons are:

1. The usage of `exit /B` for exiting batch file processing and `goto :EOF` for exiting processing of a subroutine makes it easier to see which processing is exited – a subroutine or the batch file processing. It makes it easier finding the exit points of the batch file.
2. The command `goto :EOF` does not work with disabled command extensions. The second line of the batch file explicitly enables the command extensions. `goto :EOF` works for that reason always for the subroutine. But it could not work for exiting the batch file processing after the command line with `endlocal` on command extensions are disabled for whatever reason in initial environment on starting the processing of the batch file.
3. The command `exit /B` always works even with disabled command extensions. It would be even better to use `exit /B 2>nul` to suppress the error message output because of missing label `EOF` on running `exit /B` in initial execution environment with disabled command extension. However, command extensions are enabled by default on nowadays used Windows versions. There is really no reason to disable them ever, except a batch file is written on Windows XP and newer Windows versions for usage on MS-DOS, Windows 3.1, Windows 3.11, Windows 95/98/ME with `COMMAND.COM` as command interpreter instead of the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Maybe this doesn't matter, but with `exit /B <code>` to return from a subroutine instead of `goto :EOF`, the caller will have access to an exit code, for use in `if errorlevel` or checking `%errorlevel%`. You would also be able to set environment variable(s) though, which the caller could access, which could be non-integer values. That would be somewhat analogous to a function setting global variables before it returns in other programming languages.

Comment: @RichJahn That is right. But I write batch files since more than 30 years and wrote thousands of batch files on which I have never needed to exit a subroutine with an exit code at all. Yes, `exit /B <code>` can be used to return an exit code from a subroutine to calling code and `if errorlevel` or `if not errorlevel` can be used in the calling code to evaluate the exit code of the subroutine, but I have never needed that in my batch files. There can be used an environment variable to return something from subroutine to calling routine which is much more often used as not limited to a number.