# Memory usage using batch script under Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, memory, cmd, memory-leaks

I am running the following batch script under Windows (Server 2019) to move (and rename) substantial amount of tiff files (on the order of several millions):

```
@echo off
set "mainFolder=."
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /D %%i in ("%mainFolder%\*") do (
    set "DateFolder=%%~nxi"
    set "init=1"
    
    for %%f in ("%%i\*.tif") do (
        if !init!==1 (
        echo Processing folder: !DateFolder!
        set "init=0"
        )
        set "TiffFullPath=%%~dpf"
        set "TiffPExt=%%~nxf"
        set "Tiff=!TiffPExt:~0,-4!"
        if not exist %mainFolder%\..\clus\!Tiff! mkdir %mainFolder%\..\clus\!Tiff! >nul
        move /y %%f %mainFolder%\..\clus\!Tiff!\!Tiff!_!DateFolder:~7,8!.tif >nul
    )
)
echo Done
```

When I monitor Task Manager I see that the RAM memory consumption increases constantly from about zero to maximum (32 GB) in about 30 minutes and eventually I got "Not Enough Memory Resources Are Available To Process This Command".

What could be the cause of that, since I understand moving a file only involves changing pointer/reference in the OS so memory shouldn't be increase at all.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading first [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**. There is supposed the usage of the command **SETLOCAL** somewhere inside the two **FOR** loops without a matching **ENDLOCAL** which would explain a permanently increasing usage of memory until an end of free stack memory error condition occurs during the batch file processing. But the posted code contains **SETLOCAL** only once at top of the batch file. There should be no increasing memory usage with the posted code. The posted code is most likely not complete and misses the part responsible for the continuously increasing memory usage.

The posted code fails to process files of which full name (drive + path + name + extension) contains one or more exclamation marks. There is below a variant of the batch file which does not make use of delayed variable expansion for working for any TIFF file names independent on file extension being `.tif` or `.tiff` which are both found using the wildcard pattern `*.tif` as the short 8.3 file extension for a `.tiff` file is `.TIF`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "MainFolder=."
for %%I in ("%MainFolder%\..\clus") do set "DestFolder=%%~fI"
(for /D %%I in ("%MainFolder%\*") do if exist "%%I\*.tif" set "DateFolder=%%~nxI" & call :MoveFiles "%%~fI") & echo Done& exit /B
:MoveFiles
echo Processing folder: "%DateFolder%"
for %%J in ("%~1\*.tif") do mkdir "%DestFolder%\%%~nJ" 2>nul & move /Y "%%J" "%DestFolder%\%%~nJ\%%~nJ_%DateFolder:~7,8%%%~xJ" 1>nul
```

The last line could be problematic if one of the files could not be moved because of the file is currently opened in an application, or the destination folder could not be created before depending on the file system of the storage media. Better would be as last line:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in ('dir "%~1\*.tif" /A-D-L /B 2^>nul') do mkdir "%DestFolder%\%%~nJ" 2>nul & move /Y "%~1\%%J" "%DestFolder%\%%~nJ\%%~nJ_%DateFolder:~7,8%%%~xJ" 1>nul
```

The disadvantage of this line is starting for each folder with at least one TIFF file in background one more `cmd.exe` for running the command **DIR** to output a list of matching file names without path including those with hidden attribute set which are ignored by **FOR** in the last command line of the entire posted batch file. **FOR /D** ignores also directories with hidden attribute set.

**Note:** If there is in the destination directory a file with destination file name with read-only attribute, the command **MOVE** would prompt the user of the batch file despite the usage of its option `/Y` if the read-only file should be overwritten. This prompt cannot be seen because of `1>nul` at the end of the command line. Press key <kbd>N</kbd> whenever it looks like the batch file stopped moving the files for answering the invisible overwrite prompt with **NO**.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `mkdir /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&` used multiple times for faster processing of the batch file by reducing the number of lines in the batch file read during execution of the two **FOR** loops.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of files that will be processed in a folder is *huge*, then the `for %%f in ("%%i\*.tif") ...` command could exceed its internal buffers before start processing the files.

The code below not just avoid this problem by storing the file names in a text file, but also performs the task in the most efficient (fastest) way:

```
@echo off
set "mainFolder=."
setlocal EnableDelayedeExpansion
for /D %%i in ("%mainFolder%\*") do (
    set "DateFolder=%%~nxi"
    echo Processing folder: %%~nxi
    set "DateFolder78=!DateFolder:~7,8!"

    dir /A-D /B "%%i\*.tif" > "%mainFolder%\temp.tmp"
    (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("%mainFolder%\temp.tmp") do (
        if not exist %mainFolder%\..\clus\%%~nf mkdir %mainFolder%\..\clus\%%~nf
        move /y %%f %mainFolder%\..\clus\%%~nf\%%~nf_!DateFolder78!.tif
    )) >nul
)
del "%mainFolder%\temp.tmp"
echo Done
```

This solution assumes that there is not any filename with an exclamation mark. If this is not the case a small mod is needed, but the performance will suffer accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative option, which still uses delayed expansion, *(but only where needed)*, and shouldn't cause problems with exclamation marks in your file or directory strings.

Please read the body text from the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77894915) by [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi), the majority of which is still relevant, so will not be duplicated here.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "mainFolder=."

For /D %%G In ("%mainFolder%\*") Do If Exist "%%G\*.tif" (
    Echo Processing folder: %%~nxG
    Set "DateFolder=%%~nxG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%H In ("!DateFolder:~7,8!") Do (EndLocal
        For %%I In ("%%~fG\*.tif") Do (
        If Not Exist "%%~dpG..\clus\%%~nI\." MD "%%~dpG..\clus\%%~nI" 2>NUL
        If Exist "%%~dpG..\clus\%%~nI\." (
            Move /Y "%%~fG" "%%~dpG..\clus\%%~nI\%%~nI_%%~H%%~xI" 2>NUL
        )
    )
)

Echo Done.
```

*I decided to do it this way as a speed/overhead comparison with the `Call` idea already proposed.*